# Unable to add additional information in User table using Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I want to add another table for my additional user information. And here's my schema looks like:

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users_profile', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->text('address');
            $table->enum('gender', array('M','F'));
            $table->text('phone_number');
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

And I follow the Laravel's documentation about the relationship method.
I created a model named **User_Profile** and declare it's relationship to the **User** model.

And I modified the **User**  model

```
 //relationships
    public function profile() {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User_Profile');
    }
```

**User_Profile**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User_Profile extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = [
        'user_id', 'address', 'gender', 'phone_number'
    ];

    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

Then I add using **tinker**
So it goes like this:

```
>>> $profile;
=> App\User_Profile {#671
     user_id: 1,
     address: "123 Manila, Philippines, Asia, Earth, Milky Way Galaxy",
     gender: "M",
     phone_number: "3",
     created_at: "2017-01-27 01:32:34",
     updated_at: "2017-01-27 01:32:47",
   }
```

But I got this kind of error:

```
>>> $profile->save();
Illuminate\Database\QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'flax_admin.user__profiles' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `user__profiles` (`use
r_id`, `address`, `gender`, `phone_number`, `created_at`, `updated_at`) values (1, 123 Manila, Philippines, Asia, Earth, Milky Way Galaxy, M, 09195999873, 2017-01-27 01:32:34, 2017-01-27 01:32:47))'
>>>
```

Can you help me identify where's my error? I am still new in using Laravel framework.

Comment: It's interesting that you can tinker with it but not save values. Looking at the error message it seems to think the table has two underscores `user__profiles` - I assume this isn't the case?

Comment: @James, I already did save `$profile->save()` but it returns the error message. I am also checking the double underscore but couldn't find it anywhere. I dont know why did the framework look for the `user__profiles` because as you can see in my migration it is `user_profile`

Comment: One more thing in table naming should it be always the same as my model name?

Comment: Can you post your full `User_Profile.php` model please?

Comment: You can name your tables whatever you want, you just need to make sure it maps back properly.

Comment: @James, i already edited.

Comment: Try adding this to your `User_Profile.php`: `protected $table = 'user_profiles';`

Comment: @linuxartisan, already did that but still same effect of error.

Answer (score 1):

the class name must be UserProfile not User_Profile

Comment: Ok ty, I try that. So the naming convention always camel casing?

Comment: yes, you also can set the $table property if the table has a different name

Comment: I modified my class name and I also added the $table property and still the same error. But this time the table name is corrected: `SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'flax_admin.users_profiles'`

Comment: The line should be like this: protected $table = 'users_profile' and not 'users_profiles'